# How do I check whether a WP8 device uses wifi, mobile plan or roaming to load data

Tags: c#, networking, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I plan to load only as much data as required in my app. Which means, that when the data is loaded via Wifi, I want to prefetch things. If the data is loaded via mobile plan or even roaming, I would like to ask the user.

However, I only found Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation.DeviceNetworkInformation which gives me feedback on what is available, not what is actually used. NetworkInterface.GetInternetInterface() also works, but does not give me details on whether it's roaming or not.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's solve it by myself:

There is the [Data Sense API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207005%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), which allows one to not only check whether the device is roaming, but also check whether the app approaches or is over the data limit set in Data Sense. The API also works when the provider doesn't allow to usse the Data Sense UI.

In particular, this code from the link above solves everything!

```
// Get current Internet Connection Profile.
ConnectionProfile internetConnectionProfile = Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();

// Check the connection details.
if (internetConnectionProfile.NetworkAdapter.IanaInterfaceType != IANA_INTERFACE_TYPE_WIFI)
{
    // Connection is not a Wi-Fi connection. 
    if (internetConnectionProfile.GetConnectionCost().Roaming)
    {
        // User is roaming. Don't send data out.
        m_bDoNotSendData = true;
    }

    if (internetConnectionProfile.GetConnectionCost().ApproachingDataLimit)
    {
        // User is approaching data limit. Send low-resolution images.
        m_bSendLowResolutionImage = true;
    }

    if (internetConnectionProfile.GetConnectionCost().OverDataLimit)
    {
        // User is over data limit. Don't send data out.
        m_bDoNotSendData = true;
    }
}
else
{   
    //Connection is a Wi-Fi connection. Data restrictions are not necessary.                        
    m_bDoNotSendData = false;
    m_bSendLowResolutionImage = false;
}

// Optionally, report the current values in a TextBox control.
string cost = string.Empty;
switch (internetConnectionProfile.GetConnectionCost().NetworkCostType)
{
    case NetworkCostType.Unrestricted:
        cost += "Cost: Unrestricted";
        break;
    case NetworkCostType.Fixed:
        cost += "Cost: Fixed";
        break;
    case NetworkCostType.Variable:
        cost += "Cost: Variable";
        break;
    case NetworkCostType.Unknown:
        cost += "Cost: Unknown";
        break;
    default:
        cost += "Cost: Error";
        break;
}
cost += "\n";
cost += "Roaming: " + internetConnectionProfile.GetConnectionCost().Roaming + "\n";
cost += "Over Data Limit: " + internetConnectionProfile.GetConnectionCost().OverDataLimit + "\n";
cost += "Approaching Data Limit : " + internetConnectionProfile.GetConnectionCost().ApproachingDataLimit + "\n";

NetworkStatus.Text = cost;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the System.Net.NetworkInformation namespace on WP8. This package has a static method which returns the network status. You can then switch based on this information

> NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType

More details can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.networkinterfacetype%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: That's at least a first step. However, this does not allow me to check whether roaming is being used or not.

Answer (score 0):

The phone can use both 3G and WiFi at the same time. The case I've tested - the phone haven't close existing TCP connections opened while on 3G after it found and connected to a WiFi network. If a new TCP connection is opened it'll use WiFi instead.

There's `SocketExtensions.GetCurrentNetworkInterface` extension method from Microsoft.Phone.dll that tell you which interface is used for the specified socket.

Comment: That sounds interesting. I wish my device could do this transmission as well. Shouldn't the NetworkInformation.NetworkStatusChanged event occur when it switches?
In particular I only want to disable prefetching when on mobile, do you think I could simply leave this special case out?