# How is Ethernet adapter is connected on a WP Device?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, network-interface

I am trying to get active network connection on a Windows Phone 8.0 device with the following snippet. When i disable Wifi and Mobile i expect to find no interface that is connected but interestingly an adapter with name "Ethernet" is seemed connected. What is ethernet adapter on a mobile device?

```
foreach (NetworkInterfaceInfo networkInterfaceInfo in networkInterfaceList)
{
    if (networkInterfaceInfo.InterfaceState == ConnectState.Connected)
    {
        isConnected = true;
        if (networkInterfaceInfo.InterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.MobileBroadbandGsm
           || networkInterfaceInfo.InterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.MobileBroadbandCdma)
            isMobileConnected = true;
        else if (networkInterfaceInfo.InterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211)
            isWifiConnected = true;
    }
}
```

Also is there a way to get "one active network" information? For example if both mobile and wifi is enabled and connected, how can i know which one is used actually?

Thanks

Comment: For your last partial question, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21079653/2132796) answer might help you.

Comment: If you are doing this while it is connected to a pc, then as you can share internet access from PC to phone then it shows as an ethernet adapter / local area network adapter

Answer (score 2):

You can find network type with `NetworkAdapter` class. It has property [IanaInterfaceType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.networking.connectivity.networkadapter.ianainterfacetype.aspx)
To check all the IANA interface, go [here](http://www.iana.org/assignments/ianaiftype-mib/ianaiftype-mib)

```
var profile = Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
var interfaceType = profile.NetworkAdapter.IanaInterfaceType;

// 71 is WiFi & 6 is Ethernet(LAN)
if (interfaceType == 71 || interfaceType == 6) 
{
//TODO:
}
// 243 & 244 is 3G/Mobile
else if (interfaceType == 243 || interfaceType == 244)
{
 //TODO:
}
```

Hope It helps :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
private void UpdateNetworkStatus()
{
    tbIsCellularDataEnabled.Text = (DeviceNetworkInformation.IsCellularDataEnabled) ? "Yes" : "No";
    tbIsNetworkAvailable.Text = (DeviceNetworkInformation.IsNetworkAvailable) ? "Yes" : "No";
    tbIsWiFiEnabled.Text = (DeviceNetworkInformation.IsWiFiEnabled) ? "Yes" : "No";
}
```

for more Refrence you can check out [How to detect network changes for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh487166(v=vs.105).aspx)