# How can I check Wifi is on or not in WP8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

```
  string status="";

if (DeviceNetworkInformation.IsWiFiEnabled)
        {

            if (DeviceNetworkInformation.IsCellularDataEnabled == false && DeviceNetworkInformation.IsNetworkAvailable == true)

            {
                status= "WiFi Status: On and Connected!";
            }
            else
            {
                status = "WiFi Status: On but not connected!";
            }
        }
        else
        {

            status = "Wifi is Off";

        }
```

Thanks in advance :)
I want to implement the same thing in wp8.1 but Microsoft.Phone API is not preset in WP8.1.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I check whether a WP8 device uses wifi, mobile plan or roaming to load data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21079372/how-do-i-check-whether-a-wp8-device-uses-wifi-mobile-plan-or-roaming-to-load-da)

Answer (score 0):

For Windows (Phone) 8.1 the Network Information is part of the `ConnectionProfile` in `Windows.Networking.Connectivity` namespace.

The [`IsWlanConnectionProfile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.networking.connectivity.connectionprofile.iswlanconnectionprofile.aspx) indicates if the connection profile represents a WLAN (WiFi) connection.

The [`NetworkConnectivityLevel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.networkconnectivitylevel.aspx) indicates what network resources, if any, are currently available.

```
ConnectionProfile internetConnectionProfile = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
if (internetConnectionProfile.IsWlanConnectionProfile )
{
     if ( internetConnectionProfile.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel() ==
                NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess)

     {
          status= "WiFi Status: On and Connected!";
     }
     else
     {
          status = "WiFi Status: On but not connected!";
     }
}
else
{
    status = "Wifi is Off";
}
```

You can go this route, but it is not recommended.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.networking.connectivity.connectionprofile.getnetworkconnectivitylevel.aspx):

> The GetNetworkConnectivityLevel method may take time in some cases to determine the current value of the network connectivity level. The recommended process for determining the network connectivity level is to register a handler for the [`NetworkStatusChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.networking.connectivity.networkinformation.networkstatuschanged.aspx) event on the NetworkInformation class. When a notification is received of a network status change, obtain the new connectivity level by calling the GetNetworkConnectivityLevel method on the profile returned by the GetInternetConnectionProfile method. The returned network connectivity level can then be stored for later use when needed. This also ensures that the correct ConnectionProfile is checked.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Crashing when wifi is not connected or off.