# Check if user is on a Foreign Network

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I'd like to be able to programatically determine if a user is on a foreign phone network. This would be indicated by the ⯅ icon in the phone's system tray at the top of the phone screen.  I did find this method:

```
var myConnProfile = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
bool isRoaming = myConnProfile.GetConnectionCost().Roaming;
```

However, I assume this will only return true, if the user has explicitly turned roaming on from their phone settings and they're also connected to a foreign network. The default setting is for roaming to be turned off, and in this case when they're connected to a foreign network I assume `isRoaming` will just return false. I can't simluate this scenario on my phone, or on the emulator, so I am looking for some guidance. Thank you.

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21079372/how-do-i-check-whether-a-wp8-device-uses-wifi-mobile-plan-or-roaming-to-load-da

Comment: Thanks, I did see this earlier. Again though in this code isRoaming is being used to determine whether or not to send data out. If the user has switched off data roaming from their phone settings, then it's impossible to send data out, which means isRoaming must be false I assume.